# Is this model really saturated? Is there a good alternative to an ANOVA for saturated models?

Tags: r, anova, computational-statistics, degrees-of-freedom

I have chemical data from groundwater wells that were exposed to two separate amendments of vegetable oil and monitored over several time points. I am trying to set up a 2-way ANOVA to test if the chemical changes in the first exposure are significantly different than the second exposure. One of the well's data looks like this:

```
        Well Day Injection Nitrate Sulfate Acetate   Iron Uranium
    25 MLSB3   1   Primary   2.598 119.114    0.00 0.0165  2.0661
    26 MLSB3   2   Primary   0.000  66.185  387.00 3.2114  2.2684
    27 MLSB3   3   Primary   0.000   0.672 1570.00 3.8652  0.1404
    28 MLSB3   4   Primary   1.029   1.354 1720.00 1.2429  0.0547
    29 MLSB3   5   Primary   0.639  27.761  529.00 0.3887  0.2285
    30 MLSB3   6   Primary   0.000  17.675 1140.00 2.1122  0.2737
    31 MLSB3   1 Secondary  25.130  57.320    1.59 0.1425  1.1115
    32 MLSB3   2 Secondary   1.870  65.570    0.00 0.0325  1.2733
    33 MLSB3   3 Secondary   0.230  20.560  494.53 1.7601  0.6412
    34 MLSB3   4 Secondary   0.000  13.360  274.10 0.3374  0.5086
    35 MLSB3   5 Secondary   8.925  58.649    0.00 0.0102  1.4936
    36 MLSB3   6 Secondary   6.853  59.213   10.00 2.1971  0.6751
```

So, for each analyte, I am doing an ANOVA comparing the two injections. One of said ANOVA models is set up like so:

```
 MLSB3_n2<- aov(Nitrate ~ Injection * Day, data = ps_MLSB3)
```

When I go to look at the ANOVA table, however, this happens:

```
               Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
Injection      1    125   125.1
Day            5    270    53.9
Injection:Day  5    189    37.8
```

And there are no p-values. After searching around, I found out this is most likely because the model is "saturated", meaning there are no more degrees of freedom left in the model to estimate variance. However, I think that might not be the case.

I have two factors- one with 2 levels and one with 6 levels, I can't figure out how they would run out of degrees of freedom. Is the model itself wrong? If the model is correct- is there any way to calculate the significance of their interaction without using an ANOVA?

Sorry if this question is very long, I just wanted to make sure I explained it well. Any and all help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Simply call `summary(MLSB3_n2)`. See `?aov`. Some documentation pages have examples at the end.

Comment: Sorry should have specified, the resulting ANOVA table is what comes up when using `summary(MSLB3_n2)`, i.e. no p-values included.

Comment: I now see why. The response you got about saturation was correct. When you include the interaction, you now have a unique value of a predictor term for each data point, such that there is no uncertainty to contend with. If you have a predictor that has a 1:1 relationship with the outcome, then you have perfect prediction, zero uncertainty. If you take out the interaction, or include data from additional wells, then things should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Since I have five wells total, should I include well as another factor? Or can I just analyze the wells together instead of individually?

Comment: If well does not change in the data, then it cannot be a factor, so you cannot add well to the model with the data as is. You can put all wells in a single model, then add a factor for well in that model.